# Центрирование графика внутри блока

Tags: css

Есть блок на сайте и график, внутри этого блока. Как сделать так, чтобы график был центрирован внутри этого блока и был растянут по всей высоте этого блока? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

```css
.token {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */
  text-align: center
}

.token__inner {
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section class="token" id="token" style="height:1000px">
  <div class="token__inner">
    <h2 class="token__title">Token Distribution</h2>
    <div id="piechart" style=" width:90%; height: 90%px; margin:auto;text-align: center; "></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Сделайте нормальный сниппет чтобы можно было воспроизвести вашу проблему или используйте codepen\jfiddle и т.п. соервисы

Comment: @Nilsan https://jsfiddle.net/p28nyzrd/